# How can I pass a variable into 'window.open'?

Tags: javascript, variables, popup, size, window.open

I'm having some trouble with a `window.open` action in JavaScript, and could do with some pointers (I've searched everywhere!). I want to set the width and height to values of variables which I defined earlier on (and are set depending on what time it is). Here is the code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 10.1" />

    <script type = "text/javascript">

var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();

m = Math.round(parseInt(m)/5)*5;

var x;
var y;

function test() {getY(); getX(); alert(h); alert(m); alert(y); alert(x);}


function getX() {

if (m==0)
    {x=200;}
else if (m==5)
    {x=210;}

***CONTINUED DOWN TO:

else if (m==50)
    {x=290;}
else
    {x=300;}
}


function getY() {

if (h==0)
    {y=200;}
else if (h==1)
    {y=210;}


***CONTINUED DOWN TO:

else if (h==22)
    {y=420;}
else
    {y=430;}

}


var openWin = function(){window.open('','','width=x,height=y')};

</script>

</head>
<body onload="test()">
<input type="button" value="Open Window" onclick="openWin()" />
</body>
</html>
```

I have some alerts set on load to check that the variables are being set correctly, which they are... so I don't know what the problem is!! If I put numbers in the `window.open` statement it works fine as well.

Comment: What is `***CONTINUED DOWN TO:`?

Comment: getX() should probably be `x = 200 + m * 2;` and getY() should probably be `y = 200 + h * 10;` but maybe I'm just lazy.

Comment: good point! that would have been a much quicker way to to it.

Comment: the continued down to is just because there's a load of repetivite code so i took it out when i posted it on here because otherwise it'd be really long

Answer (score 2):

`'width=x,height=y'` is a string.  `x` is a character, not a variable.

You want to concatenate the *value* of the variable into the string:

```
"..." + x + "..."
```

Comment: so would that be like   

    var openWin = function(){window.open('','',"width="+x+",height="+y")}

I tried that earlier (and a few different variants of it also) and it doesn't work. :/

Answer (score 0):

After trying out your code I got one possible solution for your problem.
Change your code so that function

> getX() returns x

and

> getY() return y

and then change the parameters of the function `window.open()`:

`var openWin = function(){window.open('','','width='+ getX(),'height=' + getY())};`

Comment: Yes. I have tested it with firefox and it works. EDIT: Meanwhile I have tested it on chrome and it works.